# How can i count frequency AMT by ABCD?

Tags: r

```
C1:
  AMT A B C D
1 13  0 1 0 0 
2 17  0 0 1 0 
3 19  0 0 0 1
4 1   0 0 1 0 
5 9   0 1 0 0
```

How can i count frequency AMT by ABCD?

```
C2= t(as.matrix(C1[1])) %*% as.matrix(C1[2:5])
```

It gives me a result of Total Sum by Region.

My desired output to combine A B C D in one col since it is binary then count frequency by Type. ie.

```
  AMT GROUP N
1 1    A    1
2 9    B    1
3 13   B    1
4 17   C    1
5 19   D    1
...
AMT IS NOT LIMITED TO 1 9 13 17 ... RANGE FROM 0-30
```

```
res <- C1 %>% group_by( ) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
C1 %>%  
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = A:D,
    names_to = "Names", 
    values_to = "Values",
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Names) %>% 
  filter(Values == 1) %>%
  summarise(AMT = sum(AMT))
  select(Names, AMT, -Values)
```

Output:

```
  Names   AMT
  <chr> <dbl>
1 B        22
2 C        18
3 D        19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max.col` to get the column name which has value 1 in it.

```
library(dplyr)

C1 %>%
  transmute(AMT, 
            GROUP = names(.)[-1][max.col(select(., -1))], 
            N = 1) %>%
  arrange(AMT) -> res

res

#  AMT GROUP N
#4   1     C 1
#5   9     B 1
#1  13     B 1
#2  17     C 1
#3  19     D 1
```

**data**

```
C1 <- structure(list(AMT = c(13L, 17L, 19L, 1L, 9L), A = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L), D = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```